# Insert same variables and values into multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a stored procedure with SQL that will allow me to insert multiple values into multiple tables. Some of the tables share the same data, which requires me to insert the same values into each table. I tried inserting using the same variable, which doesn't seem to work.

The goal is to save time, inserting data into all the tables simultaneously would be much better compared of having to go through each table running one query at a time. The NULLS below actually represent columns with data, left NULL for the sake of testing.

What could I do to make it function? Any idea of an approach that works?

```
 create proc InsertMultipleValues
    (
    @BusName varchar (50),
    @BusReg varchar (10),
    @Invoice varchar (50),
    @Receipt varchar (50),
    @Total varchar(20),
    @KioskID varchar(50), 
    @Date date
    )
    AS
    Begin
            Insert into GAFSupplies values 
            (newid(), @BusName, @BusReg, @KioskID, @Date, @Invoice, NULL,
            NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, @Date)

            Insert into GAFLedgers values 
            (newid(),@Date, NULL, @KioskID, NULL, NULL, @BusName, NULL, 
            @Invoice, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, @Date)

            Insert into Renewals values (newid(), @BusReg, NULL, 'T', NULL, NULL, 
            @BusName, NULL,
            900, 'B', NULL, @Receipt, NULL, NULL, @KioskID, NULL, @Date)
End
```

[The screenshot shows the error when running the stored procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HurMr.png)

Comment: an error is saying that table column and insert statement columns does not match

Comment: please check table columns

Comment: have you checked with no. of columns to passing values

Comment: checked and solved. Works now. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you are missing values for some columns. Provide column names in Insert statement

Insert into GAFSupplies(Column1,Column2) values (1,'Test')

Comment: Yeah, Thanks! I actually missed out one column for the Renewal Table.

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because columns in your table and input values are not matching.
So specify column names and values in the insert query
eg:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN1, COLUMN2,COLUMN3) VALUES (VALUE1,VALUE2, VALUE3)
```

This is the best practice. In this case if u add an additional column in your table (for temporary purpose), it will not affect the existing insert query.